# Safari on iOS, is there any event before virtual keyboard pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

I'm developing a iOS browser application(html + javascript), and there's something wrong with the fixed-bottom(from twitter bootstrap) feature when virtual keyboard is pop up, so I want to disable it before virtual keyboard is pop up. Is there any event can do that ?

I've tried `focus` event when focusing an input field, but it's too late, the fixed bottom element will be already affect by virtual keyboard, Any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried on checking mousedown / touchstart which occurs before the focus? Just check whether the event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() is "input" or "textarea" when it's dispatched.

I've also created https://github.com/zvona/Servant.js, which is an initial version of advanced keyboard handling. It supports "keyboardshow" but not "beforekeyboardshow". I'll check whether it can be implemented and to help in your case.

.

Comment: Just remember that when user scrolls the view and touches an input element, it may cause an unwanted event.

Answer (score 1):

Please check **onresize** event of **body** element in your html.

if you are using jquery you can use [this](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C you would register for one of the keyboard notifications. The one you would need is called UIKeyboardWillShowNotification. I don't know what literal string that translates to. I'd have to write a bit of code in order to figure out the string literal.

I don't know if you can register for notifications in Javascript.

Comment: I'm using Javascript and HTML only :D